# What's the easiest way to read a page's elements,find the designated numbers and write it to the page?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My plan is to inspect the  page source (the that pops up after pressing F12).
Find the specific number(s) and write them down on the same page and if possible press the button (continue).
I researched a bit and what I think is that I could co-operate BeatifulSoup to find the numbers and insert them to Selenium to do the rest of the job.

Comment: Selenium can do this fine. What's the problem?

Comment: Can Selenium both find and write it down and possibly press the continue button?
If so could you please elaborate or give me a starting point?

Comment: Selenium can interact with the DOM, yes. I don't have examples, but I'm sure there are plenty of external tutorials for it